# Boost not refreshing views page

Tags: caching

I am using Drupal 7.32 and the latest Boost, Boost Crawler and Cache Expiration modules. My 'normal pages' refresh fine with boost when i amend them ie. articles, Basic Page, Content Type node, but if I change a node which belongs to a Views page (e.g. a News item on a News Blog page contructed with a View), then it does not pull in the latest news item i have just created i.e. does not expire the News Blog page. Within the documentation at https://www.drupal.org/node/545908 it shows the option

```
[x] Clear all cached views pages associated with a node on update/delete
```

But I cant see where to set this in the Boost module settings. I think that would fix my problem. Maybe that is referring to old documentation, perhaps the new module does it in a different way.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging around I found that this is resolved by adding the URL to the Cache Expiration setting as follows. Go to » Administration » Configuration » System >> Cache Expiration, the under Node Expiration tab, then in the section 'What URLs should be expired when node action is triggered?', tick Custom Pages, then add the URL of your pages that are created with Views, in my case its just the word News. There may be a way to add conditioning on this so it only expires the News page when nodes relating to it are amended. If anyone finds that out, can they let me know. You can also tick under Module Status in the Debug section at the bottom 'Watchdog + site message ', it will display a message show which urls have been expired (cleared).